# Can elasticsearch instances with different settings join the same cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, high-availability, elasticsearch-2.0, splitbrain

I have a 2-node ES cluster. I recently enabled scripting using the following:

```
script:
  inline: true
  indexed: true
```

I know this requires me to restart the ES service, so I decided to follow this rolling restart guide:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_rolling_restarts.html

So I tried to restart the ES service on the node with all the primary shards and verified that the replica shards on the other node had been promoted as primaries. The problem is the restarted node is also reporting primary shards and can't join the cluster. I'm assuming it's because a cluster can't have 2 masters.

So my question is, how did my cluster get 2 masters? Is it because of split-brain (1 node restarted too fast thinking it's still the master) or is it because the different settings on the 2 nodes making it impossible to join the same cluster?

Comment: Could be split braing. What's your `minimum_master_nodes ` value?

Comment: it's currently set to 1. ahh, should I have stopped the service and made sure the replicas were promoted to primaries before starting it again? After both clusters reported being master, I've tried killing the instance on the said node, waited for a while and brought it back up, but it always turned up being master as well. I had to restart the other before they were able to join the same cluster.

Comment: You could so that or just try to set replica node as master:false or just art minimum amount of master notes to 2. Formula for it is n/2+1 where n is amount of nodes in your cluster. Having three nodes would be safer

Comment: yes, I've also tried setting it to node master false before starting it again, but oddly enough, it doesn't bind to 9200 as it normally would without the setting, but I can verify the process is running.